# How do I toggle between connect and connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a MySQL Database with an array called **connectionList** . The array for a user contain several objects with a **senderID** and **receiverID** fields and would sometimes be empty if the user has no pending connection request.

I have successfully mapped through the array to fetch out the data to the browser. I am however having issues when I have to use the ifelse statement to make a button toggle between **connect** if the connectionList array is empty or doesn't contain a senderID that matches the id of the logged in user and **connected** if the array contains an object having a senderID id that matches the id of the logged in user. I need assistance on what to do.

**What I have done**

```
{connectionList && connectionList.map(function (conn){
if(conn.senderID === user.id){
       return <>Connected</>
} else {
       return <>Connect</>
}
})}
```

Comment: Typo.  Your function syntax is wrong.  Either use the `function` keyword **or** use the `=>` arrow syntax.  Not both.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It works  well if the user ID is present. It shows connected but when the array is empty, it shows neither connect nor connected. It just stays blank

Comment: Now that you've corrected the typo, have you re-tested the code?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Because when I test it, [your code demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-forest-y5v3lq?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I didn't make that error on the actual code. I just did while typing the question.

Comment: Well, we can't see "the actual code".  We can only see what is presented in the question.  And the code in the question (1) had a syntax error and (2) now works as expected.

Comment: when the ```connectionList``` is empty, it wont go to the ```.map()``` so neither connect nor connected will be rendered

Comment: @SrushtiShah how do I fix this please

Comment: In which cases should the outcome be Connect and in which Connected? In particular for 0, 1 and more elements in the list?

Comment: @A_A it should be connect when the loggged in user id is not any of the senderID of objects found in the array or if the array is empty. Meaning the user has no connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (?.) in combination with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): The `.some(conn => conn.senderID === user.id)` checks if the callback is true for at least one element in it (in your case at least one connection is from the current user). The `?.` is an optional shortcut which returns undefined if `connectionList` is undefined or will call the method if it's not undefined.

Together this will return `<Connected>` if at least one connection sender is the current user, else `<Connect>`.

```js
{
  connectionList?.some(conn => conn.senderID === user.id) ?
    <Connected>
    : <Connect>
}
```

On a side note: you don't want to use `.map` except if you want one result per element in the list. In your case you only want one result for the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by below code

```
{
        connectionList ?
            <>
                {connectionList.map(conn => {
                    <>
                        {conn.senderID === user.id ?
                            <>Connected</>
                            :
                            <>Connect</>
                        }
                    </>
                })}
            </> 
            :
            <>Connect</>
    }
```